# racket pattern matching do none greedy match

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, racket

Pattern matching in Racket-language has `...` to do greedy matching( match 0 or more ), what if I want to match something like this:

```
#lang racket

(define (Modifier? t)  (equal? t "Modifier"))

(define (SimpleName? t)  (equal? t "SimpleName"))

(define (SimpleType? t)  (equal? t "SimpleType"))

(define (FieldDeclaration? t)  (equal? t "FieldDeclaration"))


(match (match '("FieldDeclaration" ("Modifier") ("Modifier") ("SimpleType") ("VariableDeclarationFragment" ("SimpleName") ("StringLiteral")))
   [(list (? FieldDeclaration? id) (? Modifier? m) ... (? SimpleType? t) (list _ (? SimpleName? n)) _ ...)
'yes]

   [else 'no] )
```

which print `'no` ,while I expect `'yes`. I guess it caused by `...` [which do a greedy matching](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) (just search "greedy" in the linked page) ,However I'm not quite sure about this ....)

there can be 0 to 3 `("Modifier")` s in the list, so **how can I match this form?** ( Actually ,there are more things to do in the function `XXX?` so I have to use the form `(? XXX? x)` )

PS: Does it possible to [extend the matching syntax](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/match..rkt%29._define-match-expander%29%29) so I can use something like `n_m` which means matching n to m times  ,just like `{n,m}` in regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `...` isn't greedy and you were very close to having it
working. Two problems:

First, three of your predicates were wrong. Since your input is
e.g. `("Modifier")` not `"Modifier"`, you want to
match `(list "Modifier")` not `"Modifier"`.

```
(define (Modifier? t)
  (equal? t (list "Modifier")))

(define (SimpleName? t)
  (equal? t (list "SimpleName")))

(define (SimpleType? t)
  (equal? t (list "SimpleType")))
```

This predicate is OK:

```
(define (FieldDeclaration? t)
  (equal? t "FieldDeclaration"))
```

Second, I think you had a misplaced closing paren in the final part of
your template -- it should be `(list _ (? SimpleName? n) _ ...)`
not `(list _ (? SimpleName? n)) _ ...`.

Here's the full match expression, I put in some line-breaks to make it
more readable to me:

```
(match '("FieldDeclaration"
         ("Modifier") ("Modifier")
         ("SimpleType")
         ("VariableDeclarationFragment" ("SimpleName") ("StringLiteral")))
  [(list (? FieldDeclaration? id)
         (? Modifier? m) ...
         (? SimpleType? t)
         (list _ (? SimpleName? n) _ ...))
   'yes]
  [_ 'no])
```

This prints `'yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Greg writes, "Actually ... isn't greedy", but the ... is greedy as shown in these examples:

```
racket@match.rkt> (match '(1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7 3 8) [(list a ... 3 b ...) (list a b)])
'((1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7) (8))

(match '(1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7 3 8) [(list (? number? a) ... 3 b ...) (list a b)])
'((1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7) (8))
```

I had expected to see '((1 2 7) (4 5 3 6 7 3 8)). I've run into problems in matching where I want the prefix, but am getting the greedy behavior.